# Pydoc webserver does not work on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pydoc

I did pydoc -p 5555 and I get - : [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '-p' for one of my modules. Is this because of corrupt python installation or am I missing something?

I am running Python 2.6.6. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ python -m pydoc -p 5555
```

If this does not work, it may be a corrupt Python Installation

Comment: Tried your suggestion, now it doesn't list my modules only the standard ones.Oh well, I will reinstall Python then.

Comment: Does it list the standard library modules? If yes, then there is no problem with your Python installation.